# Should I disable iptables when I'm using csf?

Tags: centos, firewall, iptables, csf

Should I disable iptables when I'm using csf ?
any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, you will be using [iptables](http://www.configserver.com/cp/csf.html) as it is the firewall implementation under Linux. It will be just a wrapper or another interface.

Comment: thanks, so if I disable iptables, will csf still work correctly ?

Comment: @Semi: I am not sure, but if csf uses its own scripts and config files it should work. I think you don't need to disable iptables. Just leave it to csf.

Answer (score 0):

CSF relies on iptables.  From what looks to be the homepage, assuming I have the right product,

> This suite of scripts provides:
>
> ```
> Straight-forward SPI iptables firewall script
> ```

Like most Linux 'firewalls' it's just a wrapper, as Khaled said, which writes the iptables rules for you, although CSF then appears to provide additionally checking and traffic analysis.

So, the answer is no, you should not disable iptables.

Comment: thanks, but when I did "service iptables stop" csf still works fine. and there is a tut on the net that turns iptables off. as csf is based on iptables but I'm afraid of these two firewalls rules compatibly. http://www.coolestguyplanettech.com/how-to-disable-the-linux-firewall-and-use-csf/

Comment: iptables functionality in the kernel and an iptables service are not the same thing.  I assume the iptables service is just a basic script which loads an iptables config at boot.  In summary, your question isn't clear enough.